# TypeError: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, jwt, passport-js

Estou tendo alguns problemas com Passaport.js.

Quando tento rodar minha api, o terminal me retorna um erro. Fui no arquivo em questão e não encontrei nada errado.

Dei uma pesquisada na net, mas as soluções que encontrei deixavam o código de acordo com o que eu tenho agora. Então não sei o que pode estar errado.

O erro retornado é esse:

```
/var/www/html/express/app/learnapp/auth.js:9
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()
                             ^

TypeError: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/express/app/learnapp/auth.js:9:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/express/app/learnapp/app.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

O código do arquivo auth.js é esse:

```
var passport = require("passport");
var passportJWT = require("passport-jwt");
var users = require("./users.js");
var cfg = require("./config.js");
var ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
var Strategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
var params = {
  secretOrKey: cfg.jwtSecret,
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()
};

module.exports = function() {
  var strategy = new Strategy(params, function(payload, done) {
    var user = users[payload.id] || null;
    if (user) {
      return done(null, {id: user.id});
    } else {
      return done(new Error("User not found"), null);
    }
  });
  passport.use(strategy);
  return {
    initialize: function() {
      return passport.initialize();
    },
    authenticate: function() {
      return passport.authenticate("jwt", cfg.jwtSession);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Tem um caracter que aparentemente não era para estar ai **"^"**

Comment: Isso aí é gerado no terminal mesmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Migrating from 2.x.x to 3.x.x

The extractor was replaced with ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(). The removal of ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader() was done to clearly change the API so any code relying on the old API would clearly break.

[Check Official Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt)

---

Migrando do 2.x.x para p 3.x.x

O extractor foi trocado por `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()`. A remoção do `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()` foi claramente feita para mudar a API para que qualquer código dependendo da antiga se quebre.

Comment: Este é o stack em português, por favor, traduza sua resposta para nosso idioma.

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado!!

Comment: Eu sei, isso é uma pilha em Portugal, mas eu enfrento o mesmo problema há algum tempo atrás e eu encontrei na pilha por isso eu respondo. Use o google tradutor inglês para português :)

Answer (score 0):

Para quem não estiver funcionando com

`ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()`

Tente com o seguinte:

`ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt")`